# Correlacion en R ecuación

Tags: r

Estoy realizando una correlación y neceisto visualizar los valores del 95% de confidencialidad de los datos y la ecuación en la imagen. Uso el siguiente código

X es una matriz que contiene las columnas: Diversidad.Trofica y C.A

```
Diversidad.Trofica C.A
              0.43 25.0
              0.54 10.0
              0.46 10.0
              0.35 10.0
              0.51  7.5
              0.69 35.0
              0.69 35.0
              0.55 80.0
              0.62 65.0
              0.69 85.0
              0.70 82.5
              0.38 80.0
              0.41 50.0
              0.57 75.0
              0.60 70.0
              0.34 60.0
              0.46 20.0
              0.21 15.0
              0.13 50.0
              0.06 25.0
              0.54 45.0
              0.46 25.0


cor.test(x=uno$Diversidad.Trofica, y=uno$C.A)

with(uno, plot(x=C.A, y=Diversidad.Trofica, pch=20, col='blue3',
                 xlab='Cobertura de algas', las=1,
                 ylab='Diversidad.Trofica'))
```

Comment: Hola Asiel. ¿A qué te refieres con visualizar? ¿A hacer algún tipo de gráfico? Si es así no se posible graficar un coeficiente de correlación, aunque podrías hacer algo muy parecido graficando un modelo lineal con una recta y un intervalo de confianza en forma de banda.

Comment: Lo que me refiero es que en la grafica (plot) se visualice la ecuacion y el 95% de confianza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible hacer una visualización del coeficiente de correlación o del intervalo de confianza paramétrico de la correlación. Lo más parecido que se me ocurre es presentar el gráfico de dispersión de dos variables, la recta de ajuste de un modelo lineal y unas bandas presentando los intervalos de confianza de ese modelo.

Va el código y luego una breve explicación de por qué modelo lineal sí, pero correlación no.
El código es sencillo, excepto por la parte de escribir la ecuación en el gráfico. El motor de gráficos de R permite crear expresiones matemáticas, pero tiene una sintaxis espantosa. Por eso uso una librería que toma una expresión en LaTeX y la convierte en una expresión válida en R. Es necesario ubicar manualmente el lugar en el que va a estar la ecuación como coordenadas xy.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)  #Para poder escribir la ecuación en LaTex que se me hace más fácil

tibble::tribble(
  ~Diversidad.Trofica., ~C.A,
              0.43, 25.0,
              0.54, 10.0,
              0.46, 10.0,
              0.35, 10.0,
              0.51,  7.5,
              0.69, 35.0,
              0.69, 35.0,
              0.55, 80.0,
              0.62, 65.0,
              0.69, 85.0,
              0.70, 82.5,
              0.38, 80.0,
              0.41, 50.0,
              0.57, 75.0,
              0.60, 70.0,
              0.34, 60.0,
              0.46, 20.0,
              0.21, 15.0,
              0.13, 50.0,
              0.06, 25.0,
              0.54, 45.0,
              0.46, 25.0
  ) -> foo

lm(Diversidad.Trofica.~C.A, data = foo) #De aquí tomo la ordenada al orígen y los coeficientes

foo %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Diversidad.Trofica., y = C.A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  # Ecuación del modelo lineal, es complicado y hay que hacerlo a mano
  annotate("text", 
           x=0.2, 
           y = 85, 
           label = TeX("$\\hat{y}$=0.37+0.002298x"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no es una visualización del coeficiente de correlación, es un modelo lineal. El coeficiente de correlación es una medida simétrica de la relación lineal entre dos variables. El modelo lineal indica la variación media de y cuando varía x. Algunas diferencias muy simples:

- El modelo lineal no es simétrico: la pendiente es diferente según cuál de las dos variables ubiques como dependiente.
- La pendiente del modelo lineal se expresa en unidades naturales de y y x. Para el cálculo del coeficiente de correlación de Pearson (que es el que estás usando) se hace previa una normalización de las variables, por eso siempre varían 1 y -1.
- Sin embargo son similares en un aspecto central: las dos se basan en la variación con respecto a la media (por eso son lineales).